# UICollectionView with two UICollectionViewFlowLayout

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewflowlayout

I'm working on a project in iOS, Swift. How Can we assign one collectionView with two different flow layout? Here I need my UICollectionViewCell to look like a stack-card, for that, I'm using CardsCollectionViewLayout(external pod file).

```
myCollectionView.collectionViewLayout = CardsCollectionViewLayout()
```

And it is working fine. But the issue is I cant adjust the UICollectionViewCell width with device width. For that, I need to use UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                    sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let nCol = 1
    let flowLayout = collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
    let totalSpace = flowLayout.sectionInset.left
        + flowLayout.sectionInset.right
        + (flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing * CGFloat(nbCol - 1))
    let size = Int((collectionView.bounds.width - totalSpace) / CGFloat(nbCol))

    return CGSize(width: size, height: 284)
}
```

But When I use CardsCollectionViewLayout as my collectionView layout, I did not get the call back in the above method.

OR

Is there any way to add stack-card effect with my UICollectionViewCell.

[image]

Please help me.

Comment: Can you share which pod you are using? There must be an option in the pod itself to fit it to device width. @Hilaj

Comment: pod 'CardsLayout'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UICollectionView with two flow layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56749188/uicollectionview-with-two-flow-layout)

Comment: Please consider deleting one of your two identical questions , thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56749188/uicollectionview-with-two-flow-layout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking it from a wrong prospective, if you use `CardsCollectionViewLayout` you have to use the function provided by that layout in order to change it. There's a property called `itemSize` in `CardsCollectionViewLayout`, which you can set to define the size of the cards:

```
let layout = CardsCollectionViewLayout()
collectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout
layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: YOUR_WIDTH, height: YOUR_HEIGHT)
collectionView.dataSource = self
collectionView.delegate = self
collectionView.isPagingEnabled = true
collectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
```